# Add a driver module to embedded linux

Tags: compiling, embedded, buildroot, uclinux

I have a task that consists in implementing a driver for an RF module.

The RF module communicate with the blackFin609 microcontroller using UART.

In a first step i created a uClinux image and download it in the BlackFin609 using uBoot and now i have to add the driver module to the kernel.

This is my first experience with embedded linux so i have no idea on how to add a driver module to linux.

Could you please point me to an easy tutorial, i find a lot of long tuto but i don't know from where to start, thanks in advance